# Modification of appendix entries in ToC (KOMA-Script)

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, koma-script, appendices

Four questions concerning appendix entries in the ToC:

1. As you can see in the attached picture, I want the page numbers for each appendix entry to be not bold, but normal font (like those of sections). Only the Appendix itself (introduced with a page with the word "Appendix" on it) should have a bold one because it is treated like a chapter.
2. I would like to have these dots for each sub-appendix entry (Appendix 1, Appendix 2, ...) (again like in the section entries).
3. I'm not happy with the indentation you can see in the picture if there is more than one line for a sub-appendix entry. I'd like to arrange it like demonstrated in the attached picture.
4. Is there a way to reduce the spacing between the sub-appendix entries? (analogue to the behaviour with sections, subsections, ...)

[image]

```
\documentclass[%
    fontsize        =   12pt,
    BCOR            =   10mm,
    DIV             =   calc,
    chapterprefix   =   true,
    headings        =   big,
    toc             =   bibliography,
    toc             =   listof,
    numbers         =   noenddot]
    {scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\providecommand*{\appendixmore}{}
\newcommand*{\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry}{}
\appto\appendixmore{%
\let\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
\ifstr{#1}{}{%
\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{}{#2}%
}{%
\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{}{\normalfont\small\appendixname~#1:\enskip#2}%
}%
}%
}
\usepackage[%
    bookmarks           =   true,
    bookmarksopen       =   false,
    bookmarksnumbered   =   true,
    pdfcenterwindow     =   true,
    pdfdisplaydoctitle  =   true,
    pdfencoding         =   auto,
    pdffitwindow            =   false,
    pdfstartview            =   FitV,
    draft               =   false]
    {hyperref}

\begin{document}                            

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{I am Chapter One}

\pagenumbering{arabic}                              

Test.

\section{Test}

\section{Test Test}

\chapter{I am Chapter Two}

\pagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\phantomsection                                     
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
{\Huge\bfseries{Appendix}}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

\appendix

\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}

\chapter{\texorpdfstring{I am the first appendix with a long heading that takes more than just one line}{I am the first appendix with a long heading that takes more than just one line}}

\chapter{\texorpdfstring{I am the second appendix with a long heading that takes more than just one line}{I am the second appendix with a long heading that takes more than just one line}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, to be honest, there is one chapter appendix, when you just got one appendix. Every appendix (figures, diagrams, schemes, otherStuff) should be a chapter of its own. That's why there is an `\appendix` switch, that changes the numbering scheme.

Comment: I see your point, but, unfortunately, my university guide lines say that it has to be like that. Using section instead of chapter for an appendix does not help because then it generates entries like "Appendix 0.1" or "Appendix 0.2". I'm not a professional LaTeX User so I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative solution.

[image: semeKomaTocAppendicToc]

```
\documentclass[%
    fontsize      = 12pt,
    BCOR          = 10mm,
    DIV           = calc,
    chapterprefix = true,
    headings      = big,
    toc           = bibliography,
    toc           = listof,
    toc           = indentunnumbered,%JB Optionally indent unnumbered chapters
numbers         = noenddot
]
{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{I am Chapter One}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

Test.

\section{Test}

\section{Test Test}

\chapter{I am Chapter Two}

\cleardoublepage
\appendix
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    {\Huge\bfseries\sffamily Appendix}
    \addchaptertocentry{}{Appendix}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\appendixname~\Alph{chapter}}
\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix=false}
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{#2\chapterheadmidvskip#3}
\addtocontents{toc}{
\protect\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\protect\normalfont\protect\normalcolor}
\protect\KOMAoptions{chapterentrydots}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocnumwidth=6em
]{chapter}
}


\chapter{\texorpdfstring{I am the first appendix with a long heading that takes more than just one line}{I am the first appendix with a long heading that takes more than just one line}}

\chapter{\texorpdfstring{I am the second appendix with a long heading that takes more than just one line}{I am the second appendix with a long heading that takes more than just one line}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that is quite some hacking here.

Comment: @esdd I hope you can provide a simpler solution. :-) Maybe a `leveldown` feature can be implemented, since this requirement seems to be common right now.

Comment: This solution works fine for me, now. Important for future users: Update your KOMA-Script Package, at first I got a couple of error messages because I used the KOMA version coming with MacTex 2014. After an upgrade to MacTex 2015, everything works fine. Thanks a lot to you and esdd.

Answer (score 5):

As @Johannes have said in a comment: every appendix should be a chapter of its own. It is not useful to change the behavior of chapter entries inside the ToC.

You can define an `\appendixsection` command similar to `\section` using:

```
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  indent=0pt,%
  level=1,%
  beforeskip=-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,%
  afterskip=2.3ex plus.2ex,%
  tocindent=1.5em,% same indentation as the sections
  tocnumwidth=6em,%
  font=\usekomafont{section}% same font as the section titles
]{appendixsection}
\makeatletter
  \def\toclevel@appendixsection{1}% set the toclevel for hyperref
\makeatother
```

Then you can format the entry in the ToC using

```
\renewcommand\addappendixsectiontocentry[2]{
  \addtocentrydefault{appendixsection}{\appendixname~#1:}{#2}%
}
```

[image]

and the heading in the text

```
\renewcommand\appendixsectionformat{\appendixname~\theappendixsection}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{appendixsection}{%
    #3\par#4%
  }{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[%
    fontsize        =   12pt,
    BCOR            =   10mm,
    DIV             =   calc,
    chapterprefix   =   true,
    headings        =   big,
    toc             =   bibliography,
    toc             =   listof,
    numbers         =   noenddot]
    {scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  indent=0pt,%
  level=1,%
  beforeskip=-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,%
  afterskip=2.3ex plus.2ex,%
  tocindent=1.5em,%
  tocnumwidth=6em,%
  font=\usekomafont{section}% or \normalsize if desired
]{appendixsection}
\makeatletter
  \def\toclevel@appendixsection{1}% set the toclevel for hyperref
\makeatother

% format the toc entry
\renewcommand\addappendixsectiontocentry[2]{
  \addtocentrydefault{appendixsection}{\appendixname~#1:}{#2}%
}
% format the heading
\renewcommand\appendixsectionformat{\appendixname~\theappendixsection}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{appendixsection}{%
    #3\par#4%
  }{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\appendixsection}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}% if every \myappendix should start a new page
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \phantomsection
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
  {\Huge\bfseries{\appendixname}}
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname}
}{}{}

\usepackage[%
    bookmarks           =   true,
    bookmarksopen       =   false,
    bookmarksnumbered   =   true,
    pdfcenterwindow     =   true,
    pdfdisplaydoctitle  =   true,
    pdfencoding         =   auto,
    pdffitwindow            =   false,
    pdfstartview            =   FitV,
    draft               =   false]
    {hyperref}

\begin{document}                            
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{I am Chapter One}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Test.
\section{Test}
\section{Test Test}
\chapter{I am Chapter Two}

\appendix
\appendixsection{I am the first appendix with a long heading that takes more than just one line}
\appendixsection{I am the second appendix with a long heading that takes more than just one line}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, would you say my *solution* (hack) is so bad that i should better delete it? If so, i'll gladly do. I don't like hacks. Alone, your solution feels like a hack as well. Have you seen the comment under my answer?

Comment: `appendixtoc` is also quite common it seems. Is a solid implementation planned? Alls this hacky stuff will put new users off.

Comment: @Johannes_B AFAIK `\DeclareSectionCommand` etc. will get an option `tocstyle=section` in the next version. Das eigentliche Problem ist hier der Wunsch nach einer inkonsistenten Formatierung im Dokument und im Inhaltsverzeichnis, egal welche Klasse genutzt wird.

Comment: Dann hätte ich ja gleich auf Deutsch fragen können. Ja, die Inkonsistenz finde ich auch nicht schön, aber bevor ich dafür Abzüge in der Note bekomme (ist bei mir schon vorgekommen), halte ich mich lieber an die Vorgaben. (The inconsistence is pretty bad, but some universities, unfortunately, have poor guidelines as to how to format a paper.)

Comment: @esdd: your solution works fine, but gives rise to another problem. Now, the headings in the appendix do not behave according to my guidelines. I need the format [Appendix] + [Number of Appendix] LINEBREAK [Title of the Appendix]. Is there a way to define the ToC style and the (in this case) section style independently from each other?

Comment: @SeMe Please excuse me, but get this question, along with all comments, ansers etc. to the requirement office and ask them why they are idiots.

Comment: I once asked an examiner that question and he just answered "rules are rules". The only thing is that these rules were made back in 1950s (at least it seems to be like that) and were never retouched.

Comment: @SeMe I have changed my answer to get the headings in the appendix in the desired format.